# How to optimize the mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query will take 16 seconds to get the result.

```
SELECT t.descr appSystem, t.writetime dateTime, ROUND(avg(t.cpu_avg_1),2) num FROM(
    select 
    res.res_descr DESCR,
    T9.WRITETIME,  
    ifnull(ROUND((CASE WHEN T9.kpi_no = 100000041 OR T9.kpi_no = 120000093 THEN T9.value END), 2), 0)  cpu_avg_1
    FROM res_object res left join (
    SELECT res.res_id, p.value, p.kpi_no, p.WRITETIME ,p.kbp FROM  res_object res
    LEFT JOIN pm_raw_p_reshost p ON p.kbp = res.res_id AND (p.kpi_no = 100000041 OR p.kpi_no = 120000093)
    AND res.classname='ResHost' ORDER BY p.value DESC) t9 on T9.res_id=res.res_id,
    res_node node,
    res_dim_os OS 
    WHERE node.res_id=res.res_id
    AND os.os_id=node.os_id
    AND (OS.DESCR = 'Linux' OR OS.DESCR = 'Windows')
) t WHERE t.writetime / 1000 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) 
AND t.writetime/1000 > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 day)) 
GROUP BY t.descr
ORDER BY avg(t.cpu_avg_1) DESC
LIMIT 0,15;
```

There are 13752721 pieces of data in the table pm_raw_p_reshost p, and I will get 1351461 of them by using condition `t.writetime / 1000 < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) AND t.writetime/1000 > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 day))`.

I need only consider the table pm_raw_p_reshost, the time other tables took can be ignored.

Taking 16 seconds is fastest I can do now.

How can I do to take as little as possible time to get the data I want?

Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You likely are missing and index that is necessary. I’m not sure what the data in your table looks like or what these values are, but you’ll want to make sure that any primary and foreign keys are indexed. If you were using Postgres, I’d say try running EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the query, but it doesn’t look like MySQL has a comparable tool. You could see what EXPLAIN has to say, by adding the word EXPLAIN to the very beginning of your query and running it again. If you’re doing tons of sequence scans (looking at every row), it’ll be slow compared to doing index lookups.

Comment: Another thing to think about is whether you really need to use LEFT JOIN, or whether you can use and INNER JOIN instead. An INNER JOIN will make your query faster, if it filters out rows, since your result set will be smaller.

Comment: @Nate Thank you, I just think about LEFT JOIN now, I will try it.

Comment: @Nate Well, it seems that I must request them to add an index to the table "pm_res_p_reshost" now.

Comment: Yeah, on kpi_no, I imagine. If that value is an auto-incrementing ID, and is up past 10 million, I’d say you definitely want an index on that, or else the database will have to look at each of the 10 million+ rows to know if it should include it. With an index, the database keeps track of what values of kpi_no exist and where they are in the store, so it can very quickly filter down your rows to only the ones that match that number. Additionally, you’re sorting on pm_raw_reshost.value, are you sure you need to do that?  You’re sorting again later, and unnecessary sorts will slow things down.

Comment: @Nate Thank you for your detailed answer, I have removed the first ORDER BY statement, now it only takes 3 seconds to get result.

Comment: That’s awesome!